# Will implementing counter-intuitive features and working on legacy code affect your skill?

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-mind

A problem I've had professionally a lot since I've started is that most of the feature/update recommendations I have when developing an application come from upper/middle management, people who have never touched code in their life, don't understand what clean UI is, and how app development works. These people are in positions of power and I feel like I don't have the courage to say "no" because they'll fire me if I don't implement the dumb features/UI edits.

For instance, the app i'm maintaining now is a perfect example of what I've been working on even before I started in the position I'm in: it's mostly legacy code that was the result of about four years of inane feature implementations posited by end-users who are in positions of authority and with the power to let the developer go if they don't do what they say.

I feel like this is an awful structure because if every application was in a position that the end-user could remove people from the development team for not implementing their feature suggestions then nothing would even get off the ground.

What I worry about is that if I go along with these feature implementations blindly that it will become habit forming and affect my ability to create clean and concise UI/code in a negative way.

I have two questions:

- Do you believe that working too much with legacy code that is poorly
  written will affect your skill level as a developer in a negative
  way?
- Will implementing useless features blindly become habit forming
  to the extent that you yourself forget how to do things correctly?

Comment: This all-too-common train of thought will be better received on reddit/cscareerquestions. For what it's worth, consider that you know how to build code, and management knows how to keep a company afloat, revenue coming in, and you paying the bills. It's a partnership of incompatibles. Geeks and suits, yin and yang, light and dark, Laurel and Hardy. You need both sides to have a functioning company. You want my advice? Do the best damn job you can and grumble to yourself but try to remember where the money comes from. Or find another job. https://www.reddit.com/r/cscareerquestions/